# Compute factor data between two data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have not found a solution for this, and I think it should be very simple but now I can't think right.

I have two data frames, monthly traffic volume averages, and yearly traffic volume averages. I need to divide yearly averages by monthly averages.

```
   ano mes dias  Au_TPDM  Bu_TPDM  CU_TPDM CAI_TPDM CAII_TPDM    TOTAL
1  2012 Ene   31 4288.323 620.5161 236.7419 4635.097  139.0645 6112.258
7  2012 Feb   29 3268.862 593.0000 246.3103 5191.069  147.9655 6267.286
13 2012 Mar   31 3667.903 624.7097 289.0323 5341.774  154.7419 6740.226
19 2012 Abr   30 4668.767 647.2333 281.2667 4930.433  158.3000 7236.300
25 2012 May   31 3198.581 598.9677 256.1290 5384.742  202.2581 6612.581
31 2012 Jun   30 3609.067 605.8667 280.3333 5309.500  178.7000 6795.000

 anosDB  TPDA_Au  TPDA_Bu  TPDA_CU TPDA_CAI TPDA_CAII TPDA_TOTAL
1   2012 4271.096 617.4809 255.1967 5119.454  163.5055   10426.73
2   2013 4685.079 638.5616 259.8877 5287.822  154.0110   11025.36
3   2014 4969.277 656.3918 266.8986 5407.800  177.0932   11477.46
4   2015 5184.953 541.8822 400.2137 4941.422  271.6877   11340.16
5   2016 5220.872 408.6967 541.0519 5584.492  182.4399   11937.55
6   2017 5298.852 408.7562 556.5644 6033.652  266.1644   12563.99
```

So the first 12 rows of the TPDM table should divide the first row of the TPDA table and create a new data frame which should contain monthly factors.
Something like:

```
ano mes dias FA_Au
2012 Ene 31 4271.096/4288.323
2012 Feb 29 4271.096/3268.862
```

(Don't need to show the computation, just the result)
I am sure that selecting the data by year would do that but haven't found the right way to do it.

Comment: Merge on year, then divide two columns.

Answer (score 0):

#### Merge by year and find columns to divide by position

As already mentioned by [zx8754](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885040/compute-factor-data-between-two-data-frames-in-r#comment90721705_51885040) this can be done by merging on year and dividing the corresponding columns in base R:

```
merged <- merge(TPDM, TPDA, by.x = "ano", by.y = "anosDB")
FA <- cbind(merged[, 1:3], merged[, 10:15]/merged[, 4:9])
# rename columns
names(FA) <- sub("TPDA_", "FA_", names(FA))
FA
```

> ```
>    ano mes dias     FA_Au     FA_Bu     FA_CU    FA_CAI   FA_CAII FA_TOTAL
> 1 2012 Ene   31 0.9959828 0.9951086 1.0779532 1.1044977 1.1757530 1.705872
> 2 2012 Feb   29 1.3066003 1.0412831 1.0360781 0.9862042 1.1050245 1.663675
> 3 2012 Mar   31 1.1644517 0.9884285 0.8829349 0.9583809 1.0566337 1.546941
> 4 2012 Abr   30 0.9148231 0.9540314 0.9073122 1.0383376 1.0328838 1.440892
> 5 2012 May   31 1.3353096 1.0309085 0.9963600 0.9507334 0.8084003 1.576802
> 6 2012 Jun   30 1.1834349 1.0191696 0.9103332 0.9642064 0.9149720 1.534471
> ```

**Caveat:**
This approach works as long as the positions, i.e., column numbers, of the corresponding columns are known. With the given datasets, the columns are ordered in the same way. Therefore, only an offset has to be considered to match corresponding columns.

#### Merge by year and find columns to divide by name

If, for some reason, the positions are not known in advance we can find corresponding columns by matching the column names.

For this, both datasets are reshaped from wide to long format. In long format, the column names (now called `variable`) are treated as data. Now, we can join monthly and annual values on year *and* column name, divide annual values by the corresponding monthly values, and reshape back to wide format, finally:

```
library(data.table)

# reshape and prepare monthly data
longM <- melt(setDT(TPDM), id.vars = 1:3)
longM[, variable := stringr::str_replace(variable, "_TPDM", "")]
longM[, mes := forcats::fct_inorder(mes)]

# reshape and prepare annual  data
longA <- melt(setDT(TPDA), id.vars = 1)
longA[, variable := stringr::str_replace(variable, "TPDA_", "")]
setnames(longA, "anosDB", "ano")

# join
long_FA <- longA[longM, on = .(ano, variable), 
                 .(ano, mes, dias, variable, FA = value/i.value)]

# reshape back to wide format
dcast(long_FA, ano + mes +dias ~ paste0("FA_", variable), value.var = "FA")
```

> ```
>     ano mes dias     FA_Au     FA_Bu    FA_CAI   FA_CAII     FA_CU FA_TOTAL
> 1: 2012 Ene   31 0.9959828 0.9951086 1.1044977 1.1757530 1.0779532 1.705872
> 2: 2012 Feb   29 1.3066003 1.0412831 0.9862042 1.1050245 1.0360781 1.663675
> 3: 2012 Mar   31 1.1644517 0.9884285 0.9583809 1.0566337 0.8829349 1.546941
> 4: 2012 Abr   30 0.9148231 0.9540314 1.0383376 1.0328838 0.9073122 1.440892
> 5: 2012 May   31 1.3353096 1.0309085 0.9507334 0.8084003 0.9963600 1.576802
> 6: 2012 Jun   30 1.1834349 1.0191696 0.9642064 0.9149720 0.9103332 1.534471
> ```

#### Data

```
TPDM <- read.table(text = "
i   ano mes dias  Au_TPDM  Bu_TPDM  CU_TPDM CAI_TPDM CAII_TPDM    TOTAL
1  2012 Ene   31 4288.323 620.5161 236.7419 4635.097  139.0645 6112.258
7  2012 Feb   29 3268.862 593.0000 246.3103 5191.069  147.9655 6267.286
13 2012 Mar   31 3667.903 624.7097 289.0323 5341.774  154.7419 6740.226
19 2012 Abr   30 4668.767 647.2333 281.2667 4930.433  158.3000 7236.300
25 2012 May   31 3198.581 598.9677 256.1290 5384.742  202.2581 6612.581
31 2012 Jun   30 3609.067 605.8667 280.3333 5309.500  178.7000 6795.000
", header = TRUE)[, -1L]

TPDA <- read.table(text = "
i anosDB  TPDA_Au  TPDA_Bu  TPDA_CU TPDA_CAI TPDA_CAII TPDA_TOTAL
1   2012 4271.096 617.4809 255.1967 5119.454  163.5055   10426.73
2   2013 4685.079 638.5616 259.8877 5287.822  154.0110   11025.36
3   2014 4969.277 656.3918 266.8986 5407.800  177.0932   11477.46
4   2015 5184.953 541.8822 400.2137 4941.422  271.6877   11340.16
5   2016 5220.872 408.6967 541.0519 5584.492  182.4399   11937.55
6   2017 5298.852 408.7562 556.5644 6033.652  266.1644   12563.99
", header = TRUE)[, -1L]
```